# Change Edittext aspect on a preference

Tags: java, android, preferences

I have created a custom EditTextPreference to show and inline Edittext in the preferences.
When I add it in the xml ressources file like so:

```
        <app.FormEntryPreference
            android:key="pref_key"
            android:title="@string/pref_string"/>
```

I get this result:

[image: image 1]

Which has the style I want (android:Theme.Holo).

When I add my preference programatically:

```
FormEntryPreference form0 = new FormEntryPreference(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), null);
```

I get a different result:

[image: image2]

The style is applied in the layout resource that is used for the EditText:

```
 <EditText        
    style="@style/Style.that.inherits.from.holo"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:id="@+id/form_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</EditText>
```

I'd like then to get the same kind of shape in both cases.

Comment: It's normal. When you add the EditText with the XML you are configuring the Style but when create it with the normal constructor you don't configure the style.
You have to edit your Custom EditText and set the style programatically in the contructors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so a coworker solved the problem, instead of

`FormEntryPreference form0 = new FormEntryPreference(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), null);`

I just had to remove the "getApplicationContext()" and it all worked as a charm like so:

```
FormEntryPreference form0 = new FormEntryPreference(getActivity(), null);
```